# Prove that $\iint f(x,y) dxdy = \int_{-1}^1 g(v) dv$

Tags: calculus, integration

I been trying to solve this using linear transformations but I found myself stuck, I hope someone could clear me.

Given $f : \Bbbℝ^2 \rightarrow \Bbbℝ$ , and D, a square of vertices (−1, 0), (1, 0), (0, 1) and (0, −1). And $g : \Bbbℝ \rightarrow \Bbbℝ$ such function that $ f(x,y) = g(x-y)\ \forall (x,y) \in \Bbbℝ^2$. 
Prove that: $\iint f(x,y) dxdy = \int_{-1}^1 g(v) dv$

Comment: Have you tried $v=x-y$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $C$ be that square You can use Fubini, the integral is $\int_{-1}^1(\int_{C_x}f(x,y))dx$

Here we consider $(x,0)$ an element of $[(-1,0);(1,0)]$ and the segment $C_x=\{(x-t,t)\}\cap C $, remark that On $C_x, f(x-t,t)=g(x-t+t)=g(x)$ since the length of $C_x$ is $1$, $\int_{C_x}f(x,y)=g(x)$, we deduce that $\int_Cf(x,y)dxdy=\int_{-1}^1g(x)dx$.